# Как отправить команды с сервера на клиенты

Tags: python, клиент-сервер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с помощью чего на Python  реализовать следующее:

Нужна связка клиент-сервер, например у меня на сервере стоит скрипт, который отправляет  команду на клиенты, те в свою очередь выполняют ее?

Интересует вариант, как прямая отправка команд с моего ПК на клиенты, так и через промежуточный хост. С подобным еще не доводилось работать, поэтому даже и не знаю куда копать.

Comment: посмотрите как любое чат приложение устроено (у вас ещё проще случай)

Comment: Очень общий вопрос. Начать можно с чтения [этого](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html).

Comment: что вы под командами подразумеваете? Если в узком смысле, что команды, которые в командной строчке пишутся, то можно по ssh подсоединяться на узлы и выполнять желаемые команды, к примеру, используя [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)

Comment: Под командой подразумевается отправка запроса нажать кнопку на странице сайта или ввести текст в нужную область